# Run program on init

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I would create a program (script) that launches actions when it's get run, so I'm not using routes in this program

I'm using [NestJS framework](https://docs.nestjs.com/) (requirement).

Actually I'm trying to write my code in `main.ts` file and importing a service with my methods .

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {AppService} from './app.service'
import { TreeChildren } from 'typeorm';
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
let appService: AppService; <- can't use appService methods
this.appService.
bootstrap();
```

My service

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(File) private readonly fileRepository: Repository<File>,
  ) {}

  async getTypes(): Promise<File[]> {
    return await this.fileRepository.find();
  }
}
```

I would use services to treat my operations so I sould use DI, which is not working in a non class file.

I would know how to run my operations in init time in a proper way

Comment: There’s OnModuleInit hook and you can apply it on AppModulr

Comment: Thanks you it's a way to do it, meanwhile I have found execution context: https://docs.nestjs.com/execution-context

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

### A) Lifecycle Event

Use a [Lifecycle Event](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-events) (similar to change detection hooks in Angular) to run code and inject the services needed for it, e.g.:

#### Service

```
export class AppService implements OnModuleInit {
  onModuleInit() {
    console.log(`Initialization...`);
    this.doStuff();
  }
}
```

#### Module

```
export class ApplicationModule implements OnModuleInit {
  
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
  }

  onModuleInit() {
    console.log(`Initialization...`);
    this.appService.doStuff();
  }
}
```

### B) Execution Context

Use the [Execution Context](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context#execution-context) to access any service in your main.ts:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
  const appService = app.get(AppService);
}
```

Comment: What are pros and cons of using Lifecycle Events vs Execution Context?

Comment: Although `implements` is strictly necessary in languages as Java and C#, in Typescript this is not required; I'd recommend avoiding using it at all.