# NestJS: Logging the request/response from HttpService calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, axios, nestjs

I was wondering if its possible to log the requests, response and errors using the `HttpService` from the `HttpModule`.

I used to use Interceptors from AXIOS, `HttpService` wraps axios but I can't seem to add any interceptors here, there doesn't seem to be a place in

```
HttpModule.register(...)
```

Then I thought that NestJS comes with its own interceptors and wondered if its possible to use NestJS interceptors.

I wouldn't want to apply the interceptor over a controller, service but apply it to the `HttpService`?

Any ideas, a little lost how to do this in the nestjs way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `HttpService` exposes its `axios` instance directly via `get axiosRef()`. With it, you can add an [`axios interceptor`](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

```
this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use(config => console.log(config));
```

You can for example do that in the [`onModuleInit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53484892/4694994) of your `AppModule`.

Comment: Thanks ! This allows me to continue using my original interceptors, out of interest, am I reinventing the wheel here :-) I mean, is it possible to use nestjs interceptor to do the same job - or its best to stick with AXIO interceptors.

Comment: It's not possible to use nest interceptors outside of the context of controllers, I wouldn't know how at least. 

Comment: So I think sticking with the axios interceptors is your best option here. Alternatively, you could also build a facade for the `HttpService` that does the logging. But in my opinion, using an Interceptor is cleaner

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kim Kern Is it possible to read the cookie from incoming request to controller and pass it on the interceptor for adding it in header for axios request?

Comment: don't forget to add `return config`, otherwise you might see error like mentioned [here](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware/issues/83) for `cancelToken`