# NestJS - appService instantiation problems when using dynamic providers with useFactory()

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a regular NestJS application with a module that is responsible for creating test data.

In the `AppService` class I'm calling this to create data on the startup of the application like so

```
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    constructor(dataGenerationService: DataGenerationService) {
       dataGenerationService.initData()
    }
}
```

And it works just fine.

However, ever since I added a dynamic provider for adding multi-tenancy into my application (see below) the constructor of the `AppService` is not called at all anymore.

```
const tenantContextFactory = {
    provide: TENANT_CONTEXT,
    scope: Scope.REQUEST,
    useFactory: async (request, configService: ConfigService, tenantService: TenantsService) => {
        // gets tenant ID out of the JWT token (left out of code snippet here)
        const tenantId = ...

        if (tenantId) {
            return new TenantContext(tenantId)
        }
        return null
    },
    inject: [REQUEST, ConfigService, TenantsService],
}

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Tenant])],
    controllers: [TenantsController],
    providers: [TenantsService, tenantContextFactory],
    exports: [TenantsService, tenantContextFactory],
})
export class TenantsModule {}
```

I've tried multiple ways and none of them worked

- I tried the life cycle methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479741/run-program-on-init) - but non of the `onModuleInit()` functions is called
- I tried the execution context of the same article but it says that the `dataGenerationService` is undefined, so it has an issue instantiating it
- If I remove the dependency and just have an empty constructor list with a log, then it's called, but not with the injected service.
- If I remove the tenantContextFactory of the tenantsModule providers and export arrays then also, it's called normally.

Does anyone know why the instantiation doesn't properly work anymore?

Comment: Is it not called on _startup_ or not called ever (even on request)?

Comment: neither on startup nor on requests (the goal is on startup)

Comment: What is the `DataGenerationService`? Does it inject the `TenantsService`?

Comment: it's a service in the `DataGenerationModule` and the module itself injects the `TenantsModule` and the `DataGenerationService` injects the `TenantsService` yeah

Comment: And what route are you hitting when you send a request? Does it use the `AppService`?

Comment: No, the app service is not used for any routes. The goal was just to use it for startup

Answer (score 0):

Nest is smart about what REQUEST scoped providers are created per request, and it ensures that REQUEST scoped providers are not created without a request happening. Because the `AppService` relies on `DataGenerationService` which ends up relying on `TenantsService` (which is `REQUEST` scoped), the `AppService` itself is `REQUEST` scoped and not  created at the time of startup. If you were to call a route where `AppService` is required, you'd see the constructor of the `AppService` get called, but if the requested route doesn't require that service, it won't be created in the first place.